# Installing fedora, it want to destroy /dev/sda?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, virtualbox, virtualization, fedora

I'm installing Fedora 14 in a VirtualBox VM on my Windows 7 host. I've loaded the Fedora iso and am now running the "live CD". I've followed the steps in "install to hard drive" and receive the following prompt:

```
The following pre-existing devices have been selected to be formatted, destroying all data.

/dev/sda partition table( MSDOS )
```

Is it safe to do this? Will it mess up my Windows 7 hard drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly safe.
/dev/sda is the first/primary hard drive in VirtualBox.

Nothing will happen to the host/real drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have any data on your first hard disk drive if you never used this virtual machine (made a new disk) that is not an issue, thats what sda stands for, it is absolutely save, otherwise make a backup before formatting the drive